# Non-Absolute Convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Consider the following integral, $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$. I am aware that this integral converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as seen in several related questions but I was wondering how to prove that this integral does not converge absolutely. I am unable to handle the case when $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$. Any help is much welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that
$$\frac{|\sin{x}|}{\sqrt{x}} \ge \frac{\sin^2{x}}{\sqrt{x}} =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} -\frac12 \cdot \frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{x}} $$
Now, $ \frac12 \cdot\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(2x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx \space$ Converges by  Dirichlet's test and $ \frac12 \cdot\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx \space$ diverges.
Assume $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin^2x}{\sqrt{x}} dx \space$ Converges, thus: 
 $ \frac12 \cdot\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin^2x}{\sqrt{x}}dx + \frac12 \cdot\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(2x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx \space$ Converges as a sum of convergent integrals,  and that's a contradiction. 
Thus, $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin^2x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ diverges, and by the comparison test so is $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{|sinx|}{\sqrt{x}}dx \space$ and the given integral does not absolutely converge.

Comment: I recommend using the commands \sin and \cos instead of writing just sin and cos.

Comment: @Gary Any specific reason why? looks almost the same

Comment: That is the proper function command. Otherwise it appears in italic letters which is ugly (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

In the $n^{\text{th}}$ period of $|\sin x|$, the integrand is larger than $\dfrac a{\sqrt n}$ for some $a$ (consider the interval of constant length such that $\sin x>c$).

Hence you can bound below with a diverging series.

Comment: Ah thank you very much.

Comment: Just a quick question, can you expand your answer to show the convergence of the fresnal integral as this was my main concern. since by simple substitution we can see that the given integral can be equivalent to $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(w^{2})dw$

Comment: @XiChan: nope, I am not using Fresnel.